# What is best practice to split mssql database yearly?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database in the MSSQL 2012.
Since 2013 I have all data. Now we want to split that database yearly.

For example 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018.

Challenges.
We have a table where we stored Bills. with reference to Sales Order.
If we spill then we need to carry forward pending Sales Order to next year.
Also, we want to carry forward closing stock to next year.

Each table having 2-3 lacks records in each year.

**Bills**
We doing structure of table as Transaction & TransactionDetail.

The transaction had Invoice Header & Footer details.
TransactionDetail had Product related information.

**Sales Order**
We doing structure of table as SalesOrder & SalesOrderDetail.

The SalesOrder had Order Header & Footer details.
SalesOrderDetail had Product related information.

Comment: There aren't any. it is also a very opinionated question and not a good fit for [so]. See [ask] for what are good questions for this forum.

Comment: The answer is that best practice is _not_ to do this. Data that logically belongs together should be stored in the same database for precisely these reasons...